# web page gets zoomed when i touch on input box on android mobile

Tags: android, html, css

This is the case on **android jelly bean** as it works fine when i test it on google nexus 5 with **android kitkat**. I dont want to disable zoom. Just want to stop the automatic zooming of page when input box is touched.

here is my document type and meta tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
```

input box as follows

```
<form id="search_form" class="condition_search">
      <input id="sphinx_search" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your drug name here" name="search" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
      <input type="button" value="SEARCH" name="submit" id="drug_submit"/>
    </form>
```

any solution for this?

Comment: I would like to know this as well. I've been trying to do the same thing for quite some time.

Comment: This automatic zooming is a standard function of Android OSs up to 4.1.1. Although possible, there is no official solution to this and so solutions are liable to change at any point.

Comment: If its the standard function up to Android 4.1.1, can we disable this function in any way to get rid of this.